# Create/Initialize a series of functions from data

Tags: python

I'm trying to initialize a collection of function calls based on input data, but not sure how to do this. The ideas is like below. I expect the local_v will stay unchanged once being defined. Can anyone shed some light how to deal with this or where to start with?

```
ls = [1,2]
for v in ls:
    def fn():
        local_v = v
        print(local_v)
    locals()[f'print{v}'] = fn

print1() # output: 2 expect to be 1
print2() # output: 2
```

Comment: Looks like a pattern you should probably avoid. Consider using [partial functions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial) and/or dictionaries of functions instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're trying to create is called a "closure", which is a special type of function that retains the values of its free variables. A closure is created automatically when free variables go out of scope. In your example, since you never leave the scope in which `v` is defined, your `fn` objects are ordinary functions, not closures (you can verify that by inspecting their `__closure__` property).

To actually create a closure you need to construct a new scope, inject your loop variable into that scope and then leave that scope. In python, a new scope is created for `def`s, `lambda`s, comprehensions and classes. You can use any of these, for example, given

```
ls = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
fns = []
```

you can use a helper function:

```
def make_fn(arg):
    def f():
        print(arg)
    return f    

for item in ls:
    fns.append(make_fn(item))

for fn in fns:
    fn()
```

or a lambda:

```
for item in ls:
    fn = (lambda x: lambda: print(x))(item)
    fns.append(fn)
```

or a (pointless) list comprehension:

```
for item in ls:
    fn = [
        lambda: print(x)
        for x in [item]
    ][0]
    fns.append(fn)
```

As a side note, modifying `locals` is not a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

If you want `v` to be tied to the local context, you'll have to pass it inside the function. You will also need to return a callable to `print` rather than using the `print` function directly, or else you will find that `print1` and `print2` will be `None`. And at this point, there is no need to redefine `fn`at each iteration of the loop. Something like that will work:

```py
ls = [1, 2]

def fn(v):
        return lambda: print(v)

for v in ls:
    locals()[f'print{v}'] = fn(v)

print1() # output: 1
print2() # output: 2
```

Just to try to be clearer: invoking `print1()` does not call `fn(1)`, it calls the lambda that returned by `fn(1)`.

Answer (score 0):

Better to store the functions in a dictionary rather than changing `locals`, which is likely to get confusing. You could use a nested function like this:

```
def function_maker(v):
    def fn():
        print(v)
    return fn

print_functions = {v: function_maker(v) for v in [1, 2]}
print_functions[1]()
print_functions[2]()
```

Alternatively use [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial)

```
from functools import partial

def fn(v):
    print(v)
    
print_functions = {v: partial(fn, v) for v in [1, 2]}
```

Comment: This doesn't explain the actual problem with OP's code.

Comment: @PranavHosangadi True. gog's answer covers that.